# Calculating expected value of a complex wiener process (geometric, cosine, quadratic multiplications)

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, expected-value

$$W_t$$ is defined as a wiener process.

How could the expected value of the equation below be calculated on condition that t=1?

$$Y_t = W^2_t * \cos^4(W_t)  e^{-\frac32 W^2_t}.$$

At first, I have attempted to simplify the equation partially by getting rid of the biquadratic term $\cos^4(W_t)$ through the $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$ equation but I am unable to relate and proceed further with the rest of the function terms.

An explanatory solution or help will be greatly appreciated since it is significant for me to find a solution at earliest convenience.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Hello @ozi, welcome tot MSE. If you want to edit your question properly, be sure to use MathJax. How to use MathJax is explained [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ernie060.